# How to write a file with its absolute path in prolog

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

My current code is as below. How can I add an absolute path or full path to the file? I hope to save the file in a different directory from the current working_directory. Thanks.

```
fileName('text.txt', Fname),
open(Fname, write, Stream1),
close(Stream1).
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the path with `/` as separator (even on Windows)

Going a bit overboard with the options:

```
?- open("/tmp/myfile.txt",write,Stream,alias(my_sink),encoding(utf8),type(text)]),
   write(Stream,foo(12,"Programmation en logique, très recommandée")),
   close(Stream).
```

Then there is a new file:

```
$ file /tmp/myfile.txt 
/tmp/myfile.txt: UTF-8 Unicode text, with no line terminators
```

Not sure what happens if you use a path that contains "reserved characters" - which one those are is filesystem-dependent. On Windows there are quite a few, on Unix filesystems there is generally only one: `/`. `open/N` will probably throw.

Use [`atomic_list_concat/3`](https://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=atomic_list_concat/3) to construct a path:

```
?- atomic_list_concat([my,parent,dir],'/',Path).
Path = 'my/parent/dir'.
```

Comment: Hmm .... Someone should write a Prolog interface to the [Boost filesystem utilities](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm).